# Discrete cosine transform - encode output and write it to file in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am working on a DCT implementation which will be capable of compressing images. I am stuck at the point where i get values of DCT 8x8 blocks. 8x8 block's values are stored in an arrays. Those arrays are stored in parent array which holds them all (this is not important, though).

My question is how to encode those values and write them to binary file. I am trying to create smallest file as possible. The following array is example of an 8x8 DCT block.

```
    843 -111 0 0 0 0 32 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0  -15 
     0    0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 15 0 0   0 
     0    0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0   0 
     0    0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0   0
```

How to encode it?

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.  (Also, probably best to remove "dct", as your issue is non-specific to DCTs...)

Comment: Corrected, thanks for notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPEG compression standard encodes the DCT coefficients in a [zigzag fashion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Entropy_coding) starting with the lower-frequency components. Since the higher-frequency coefficients are often zero, these are simply omitted. if I recall correctly, Huffman encoding is then used to further compress the data.

Can you use something similar here, or are the zero coefficients distributed differently in your case? If so, perhaps run-length encoding would work better.

Comment: Hi! RLE sounds promising. I have done zig-zag scan on the 8x8 block. Are there any good and easy to understand examples that could be useful for implementing RLE on array after zig-zag scan?

Comment: If zig-zag scanning eliminates most of the zero coefficients, then RLE will probably be unnecessary (especially if you're pruning the data in the same way as in the JPEG compression algorithm). I'd consider using Huffman coding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding or arithmetic coding(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) instead.

Comment: It's not necessarily that zero coefficients are removed. I think i will go for RLE after all.